# How to better solve the issue of having an entity with service dependencies on an API-like system?

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

I have created a couple of wrappers around `java.lang.reflect` classes: `JavaClass` wrapping `Class<?>`, `JavaMethod` wrapping `Method`, `JavaConstructor` wrapping `Constructor<?>`, etcetera.

Each one of them has los of getters around some properties given by their `java.lang.reflect` counterparts.

Each one of the wrapper classes also provides a set of methods that make complex computations, and they are the primary reason behind the creation of this wrapper classes, instead of the use of the original ones.

Considering for example, `JavaClass.getMethods()`:

```
/**
 * Gets us the list of all methods in the class. Includes all the methods
 * defined in the current class plus all the inherited methods.
 */
public Set<IJavaMethod> getMethods() {
    Set<IJavaMethod> javaMethods = new HashSet<IJavaMethod>();

    for (Constructor<?> constructor : clss.getConstructors())
        javaMethods.add(JavaFactory.createJavaMethod(constructor));

    for (Method method : clss.getMethods())
        javaMethods.add(JavaFactory.createJavaMethod(method));

    return javaMethods;
}
```

Notice the use of a static `JavaFactory` class. That class is a factory of a bunch of `JavaXXX` kinds of classes. I wanted to turn that static class into a instance-methods class, but that will raise the problem of having to pass into this entity a service.

Plus, it will create a problem with the following public static variables:

`JavaClass`, for instance, has a set of public static classes that are commonly used in my system:

```
public class JavaClass implements IJavaType {
    private final Class<?> clss;

    public static final JavaClass VOID = new JavaClass(void.class);
    public static final JavaClass BOOLEAN = new JavaClass(boolean.class);
    public static final JavaClass STRING = new JavaClass(String.class);
    public static final JavaClass OBJECT = new JavaClass(Object.class);
    public static final JavaClass INTEGER = new JavaClass(int.class);

       ...
}
```

I could "solve" the problem by having this method on another class, `JavaClassHelper`, but having a `JavaClass` with no way to easily access methods is awkward, at least. The reason a `JavaClass` needs a `JavaFactory` is that it constantly needs to marshal data from the `java.lang.reflect` world to my wrappers. `JavaFactory` is not the only case though of a dependency of `JavaClass`, though. I have a couple more methods that also make heavy use of some other services, although as they have an empty constructor, the code's author decided to just instantiate them right in the spot.

How to model this? In theory, the idea of just taking all the services out of `JavaClass` seems ace, but in the real world it seems to be a bit impractical, in a friendly-api sense. 
Another idea would be to have the services be passed through the constructor, and only instantiate `JavaXXX` classes through the `JavaFactory`, hiding to the outside world all these matters.

Comment: So what are you really trying to do, when and if this actually works? Did you check out how classloading works? You're in pretty deep water :-)

Comment: I tried going over all the information and did not understand what is the problem you are trying to solve - any way you can clarify on it?

Comment: I'm not sure that is wat you are looking for, but perhaps you could check the services API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: Do you use Spring or not in your project ? May you post a significant subset of your code with a runnable main class to get a better understanding of your aims and difficulties.

Comment: I'm not using any kind of IoC container.

Comment: Does Java refection API is so limited or complex to use to justify such a job ? Have you evaluate the use of AOP on the existing reflection API ? AOP may be used to replace object implementations returned thanks to dynamic proxying against original interfaces. I do not know if it suits your need - it really depends on what "complex computations" are done.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use a factory to instantiate instances of `JavaConstructor` and `JavaMethod` and you want to avoid the static references then you need to use the [Java Service Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) mechanism.

However, I think the root cause of the problem here is the use of the factory pattern in the first place.

In my experience, it's better to solve the root cause, rather than the symptoms.

What benefit does the factory provide over direct calls to the constructor of `JavaConstructor` and `JavaMethod`?

As `getMethod` already does the switch between contructors and methods, the switch provided by the overloaded method `JavaFactory.createJavaMethod` doesn't seem to provide any benefit.  Persumably the `JavaFactory.createJavaMethod` methods simply invoke the constructors of their respective return types?  So why not lose the the factory pattern, just create the objects directly via their constructors in the first place and you're left with something like this:

```
public class JavaClass 
{      
  ...

  /**
   * Gets us the list of all methods in the class. Includes all the methods
   * defined in the current class plus all the inherited methods.
   */
  public Set<IJavaMethod> getMethods() 
  {
    Set<IJavaMethod> javaMethods = new HashSet<IJavaMethod>();

    for (Constructor<?> constructor : clss.getConstructors()) 
    {
      javaMethods.add(new JavaConstructor(constructor));
    }

    for (Method method : clss.getMethods())
    {
      javaMethods.add(new JavaMethod(method));
    }

    return javaMethods;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: There is only one interface IJavaMethod, that has as implementations a JavaMethod and a JavaConstructor.

Comment: Then losing the factory still works, you just create the appropriate object and return it as a `IJavaMethod`.  Though if you're set on using the factory, then the Java Service Provider mechanism is the way forward, though imho that's overly complex for the problem you have.

Comment: Using a factory only has interest if your JavaMethod ever needs more than the method to be instanciated.